# Redirect user to subdomain for specific country

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a website www.xyz.com which has the content for a particular country X. Also I have another site target to different country Y on a subdomain of this very same domain like subdomain.xyz.com

I can use any free geo ip database and some php script to achive the redirection and I did this successfully but now the problem is

Person from country Y visiting the site www.xyz.com is being redirected to subdomain.xyz.com but he is suppose want to check www.xyz.com it again redirects them to subdoamin.xyz.com.

I want this the google way, so that if suppose a person visiting google.com from UAE is being redirected to google.ae but if they click go to Go to Google.com they are redirected to google.com without any problem.

I need to implement this for my site..

The site is in wordpress. Please suggest me the best possible solution.

**Ok Here is a code that I have used..**

```
/**
 * Example 6
 *
 * This is what google probably do with users around the world
 *
 * Multiple declatations
 */

// Start by including CountryDetector class
include("./src/CountryDetector.class.php");

// You dont need to create instance of this class you can access only on static context

// Google.co.uk
CountryDetector::redirect("AE", "http://uae.jobscow.com");

// Google Germania
CountryDetector::redirect(array("DE", "AT"), "http://google.de"); // Ausrian and German users

// Google China
CountryDetector::redirect("CN", "http://google.cn");

// Google sweden
CountryDetector::redirect("SE", "http://google.se");

// Google norwegia
CountryDetector::redirect("NO", "http://google.se");

// Google serbia
CountryDetector::redirect("RS", "http://google.rs");

// AND SO ON...

// Finally: Google.com - international
CountryDetector::redirect("international", "http://google.com");
```

?>

What changes would you suggest me to make in this

Answer (score 2):

Use referer check: if they arrive on www.xyz.com and referer is not the country site, redirect to country site.

If they click on "go to www.xyz.com" on the country site, the referer will be country.xyz.com, and then you don't redirect.

You could also use a cookie to store a customer's preference in this matter.

[RFC2616 section 14.36](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) explains the Referer header field, and [this article](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-http-referer-variable/) shows how to use it in php.

EDIT: as an alternative - because as lars states the user or something along the path could deactivate it / remove the header - you could use a virtual "landing page" on www.xyz that hints the server that the visitor came from the country server:

```
<a href="www.xyz.com/fromcountryserver.php">Go to xyz</a>
```

or why not, add a request variable that indicates that the browser came from the country server.  Silly example just to show the intention

```
<a href="www.xyz.com/index.php?comingfrom=countryserver">Go to xyz</a>
```

or a mix of these techniques.  A bit more work but unless some maniac rewrites URLs clientside it should always work.

Comment: ummm. I am aware of the fact that cookie is no more reliable than referrer, but referrer is not the way to go anyway

Comment: referer has the problem, that some firewalls and even users deactivate it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's just a cookie that Google is using for this silly trick.

Let me suggest you to navigate to google while some HTTP sniffer on. That's extremely educational enterprise.

Comment: @Jimin well, I'd say that 3xx redirects are no less important. So, it's better so see complex picture, how particular HTTP works

Answer (score 0):

1. Install GeoIP PHP Extension http://www.videochat-scripts.com/install-geoip-php-extension/
2. Detect user's country http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php
3. Redirect user if he landed on wrong site

Answer (score -1):

Use redirections on your webserver (i.e. Apache if you use it) or insert them on the pages via javascript (redirect function).

If you are using Apache, you can use mod_alias to configure your redirections if you are using MaxMind for getting the country of access (you can use other services, I suppose there is no problem on this), i.e:

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

# Redirect one country
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.canada.com$1 [L]

# Redirect multiple countries to a single page
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(CA|US|MX)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.northamerica.com$1 [L]
```

More info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

You can also get the client's address via PHP and construct a javascript function like this (but the Apache solution is more elegant):

```
function redir()
{
if(checkCountryViaIp(ip) == countryx)
{
    window.location = "countryxpage.php"
}
    //etc...
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific or if possible please share share the code

Comment: how is it supposed to let into Canada site from USA?

Comment: You can put this as configuration on your main site, but not on the subsites. All depends on how do you want to handle the access for the different sites.

Comment: @mcomghall what you explain does automatic redirections based on the originating ip and that's exactly what he wants to avoid/trap/counteract.

Comment: Imagine you have xyz.com as your main site and you make your redirections to <country>.xyz.com. You can put the configuration I give as configuration on xyz.com and let anyone access <country>.xyz.com anytime simply making them different virtual sites on your Apache configuration (or putting them on different servers).